# How to use Python closing context manager

Tags: python, file-io, with-statement

The standard library `open` function works both as a function:

```
f = open('file.txt')
print(type(f))
<type 'file'>
```

or as a context manager:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    print(type(f))
<type 'file'>
```

I am trying to mimic this behaviour using `contextlib.closing`, where `File` is my custom file I/O class:

```
def my_open(filename):
    f = File(filename)
    f.open()
    return closing(f)
```

this works as expected as a context manager:

```
with my_open('file.txt') as f:
    print(type(f))
<class '__main__.File'>
```

but of course if I call directly, I get back the `closing` object instead of my object:

```
f = my_open(filename)
print(type(f))
<class 'contextlib.closing'>
```

So, how do I implement `my_open` so that it both works as a context manager *and* returns my File object when called directly?

Full working example on github:
https://gist.github.com/1352573

Comment: That's not what `closing` is for. You use `closing` when you write the `with` to turn any object with a `close` method into a context manager. You don't use it ahead of time. The example [in the `contextlib` docs](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) seems pretty clear. If you want to be able to turn it into a context manager at any time, then Zach's answer is correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest thing is probably to implement the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods yourself.  Something like this should do it:

```
class File(object):
   # ... all the methods you already have ...

   # context management
   def __enter__(self):
       return self

   def __exit__(self, *exc_info):
       self.close()
```

It would, by the way, be more idiomatic to do the work of your `open` method in your `__init__` method.

Comment: Also possible -- just do the `close` work in `__exit__` and do `close = __exit__`, or vice versa.